Are HTML accesskeys still terrible in 2024?
accesskey is a standard attribute in HTML that allows for defining hotkey for focusing an element. Historically, many pitfalls with them has been noted. Many of them are summarized in Keyboard Accessibility - Accesskey by WebAIM.
Another question references (over 10 years old) research into what keys are used by assistive technologies. Notably, ALT + [character key] maps to many functions in the screen reader JAWS. However, current documentation for JAWS seem to indicate that those shortcuts are no longer applicable.
Modern browsers seem to have defined their modifier keys for accesskeys to not interfere with the browser. E.g. Microsoft Edge uses CTRL for most functions except for (ALT d/f, address bar, settings menu). Firefox use ALT to open the top menu, and use CTRL + ALT as modifier key for accesskeys so it should be fairly safe. Apple Safari uses CTRL + OPTION, which should also be safe since Mac hotkeys generally use CMD +/- ALT.
I have seen recommendations to prefer single character key shortcuts, but these interfere with current voice control software, and much because of this, WCAG requires a mechanism to disable them.
I have also considered making everything a WAI-ARIA widget with arrow key navigation, but that seem counter-intuitive to modern web standards that already define keyboard navigation for things like <dialog> and <summary>, that I use extensively.

In summary, assuming that accesskeys in most cases do not interfere with browsers, and modern screen readers use their own modifier keys (e.g. CAPS-LOCK), they should be OK to use in niche web apps such as business applications as a productivity boost.

Accesskeys have several issues:

They are not discoverable.
They are not consistent across websites, so the accesskey that may take you to the sitemap on one site may take you to the homepage on another site.
Interference with keyboard shortcuts defined elsewhere, not only by the browser but also by assistive technologies or user-defined shortcuts for other applications.

The first two issues have definitely not been solved. To what extent the last issue has been solved is something I haven't checked, but without solving the first two issues, I still wouldn't recommend accesskeys.
Note also that WCAG Success Criterion 2.1.4:Character Key Shortcuts (Level A) is about single-character shortcuts, not accesskeys. The success criterion's Understanding document is explicit about this:

Accesskeys are also not affected because they include modifier keys.

